# get all the unique secondary keys in a dictionary python

Tags: python

I have a 2d dictionary eg:

```
 d[a1][b1] = v1
 d[a1][b2] = v2
 d[a2][b1] = v3
 d[a2][b3] = v4
```

In the above examples the unique secondary keys are b1, b2, b3?

How do i return the list [b1,b2,b3] in python?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
s = list(set(key2 for key1 in d for key2 in d[key1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the dict could be many dimensions, the way to go about getting a list of the values from the 2nd level is to just loop through the dict as normal.

My suggestion is for you to look into perhaps using something like [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html). Itertools can help make quick and fancy work of a use case like yours.

Comment: To make this a little more specific, `list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d[k] for k in d)))` would do the trick, but I don't know if that's much better than a nested listcomp or not.  `list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.values())))` should work too.